# Modeling a small programming language and analysis in SMT-LIB using datatypes and forall

Tags: z3, smt

I am trying to model a small programming language in SMT-LIB 2.
My intent is to express some program analysis problems and solve them with Z3.
I think I am misunderstanding the `forall` statement though.
Here is a snippet of my code.

```
; barriers.smt2

(declare-datatype Barrier ((barrier (proc Int) (rank Int) (group Int) (complete-time Int))))

; barriers in the same group complete at the same time
(assert
  (forall ((b1 Barrier) (b2 Barrier))
          (=> (= (group b1) (group b2))
              (= (complete-time b1) (complete-time b2)))))
(check-sat)
```

When I run `z3 -smt2 barriers.smt2` I get `unsat` as the result.
I am thinking that an instance of my analysis problem would be a series of `forall` assertions like the above and a series of const declarations with assertions that describe the input program.

```
(declare-const b00 Barrier)
(assert (= (proc b00) 0))
(assert (= (rank b00) 0))
...
```

But apparently I am using the `forall` expression incorrectly because I expected z3 to decide that there was a satisfying model for that assertion. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a `datatype` like this:

```
(declare-datatype Barrier 
      ((barrier (proc Int) 
                (rank Int) 
                (group Int) 
                (complete-time Int))))
```

you are generating a universe that is "freely" generated. That's just a fancy word for saying there is a value for `Barrier` for each possible element in the cartesian product `Int x Int x Int x Int`.

Later on, when you say:

```
(assert
  (forall ((b1 Barrier) (b2 Barrier))
          (=> (= (group b1) (group b2))
              (= (complete-time b1) (complete-time b2)))))
```

you are making an assertion about all possible values of `b1` and `b2`, and you are saying that if groups are the same then completion times must be the same. But remember that datatypes are freely generated so z3 tells you `unsat`, meaning that your assertion is clearly violated by picking up proper values of `b1` and `b2` from that cartesian product, which have plenty of inhabitant pairs that violate this assertion.

What you were trying to say, of course, was: *"I just want you to pay attention to those elements that satisfy this property. I don't care about the others."* But that's not what you said. To do so, simply turn your assertion to a function:

```
(define-fun groupCompletesTogether ((b1 Barrier) (b2 Barrier)) Bool
   (=> (= (group b1) (group b2))
       (= (complete-time b1) (complete-time b2))))
```

then, use it as the hypothesis of your implications. Here's a silly example:

```
(declare-const b00 Barrier)
(declare-const b01 Barrier)

(assert (=> (groupCompletesTogether b00 b01)
            (> (rank b00) (rank b01))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

This prints:

```
sat
(model
  (define-fun b01 () Barrier
    (barrier 3 0 2437 1797))
  (define-fun b00 () Barrier
    (barrier 2 1 1236 1796))
)
```

This isn't a particularly interesting model, but it is correct nonetheless. I hope this explains the issue and sets you on the right path to model. You can use that predicate in conjunction with other facts as well, and I suspect in a `sat` scenario, that's really what you want. So, you can say:

```
(assert (distinct b00 b01))
(assert (and (= (group b00) (group b01))
             (groupCompletesTogether b00 b01)
             (> (rank b00) (rank b01))))
```

and you'd get the following model:

```
sat
(model
  (define-fun b01 () Barrier
    (barrier 3 2436 0 1236))
  (define-fun b00 () Barrier
    (barrier 2 2437 0 1236))
)
```

which is now getting more interesting!

In general, while SMTLib does support quantifiers, you should try to stay away from them as much as possible as it renders the logic semi-decidable. And in general, you only want to write quantified axioms like you did for uninterpreted constants. (That is, introduce a new function/constant, let it go uninterpreted, but do assert a universally quantified axiom that it should satisfy.) This can let you model a bunch of interesting functions, though quantifiers can make the solver respond `unknown`, so they are best avoided if you can.

[Side note: As a rule of thumb, When you write a quantified axiom over a freely-generated datatype (like your Barrier), it'll either be trivially true or will never be satisfied because the universe literally will contain everything that can be constructed in that way. Think of it like a datatype in Haskell/ML etc.; where it's nothing but a container of all possible values.]

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth I was able to move forward by using sorts and uninterpreted functions instead of data types.

```
(declare-sort Barrier 0)
(declare-fun proc (Barrier) Int)
(declare-fun rank (Barrier) Int)
(declare-fun group (Barrier) Int)
(declare-fun complete-time (Barrier) Int)
```

Then the `forall` assertion is sat. I would still appreciate an explanation of why this change made a difference.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was alluding to in my answer: Use uninterpreted functions and have axioms about them. But this approach also has shortcomings (due to the presence of quantifiers making the logic semi-decidable), and if you can get away with the encoding in my answer, that'd serve you better.